# jquery not able to get `visible` elements from saved `jquery object`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to retrive the `:visble:first` element from the saved jquery object. i require `first`, `last`, `first-prev`, `last-next`  for various requirement.

i tried this, but not working.

html :

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
```

jQuery :

```
var divs = $('.test'); // i stored here

console.log(divs.find(':visible:first')); //always returns 5

console.log($(':visible:first', divs)); //always returns 5
```

what is wrong with this selector?

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/hzLL40xu/)

Comment: $('.test:first:visible').css('background-color','red'); - I tried this in your fiddle and worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using filter() will search for child elements, you want to check `:first:visible` on your original query.

```
var divs = $('.test:visible:first');
```

You can also use JQuery filter to if you need to get all divs then call its first node `[0]`

```
console.log(divs.filter(':visible')[0]);
```

Or if you are wanting to keep the jquery selector you can use .first()

```
console.log(divs.filter(':visible').first());
```

Comment: May be we can use, but what is the issue with my approach? Even you approach how to get the last (last()) apart from?

Comment: The issue is you were using .find() which looks for child elements, in this case you wanted to use your selector directly. Check my updated answer